# How can I query something in Google Sheets where it returns values but leaves the filtered values as blanks

Tags: if-statement, google-sheets, google-sheets-formula, array-formulas, google-sheets-query

```
=query('Data (QC)'!B7:BE,"select C where AF !='Typist'",-1)
```

newbie query function user here.  so the above is pretty straight forward, return C except where AF doesn't include 'Typist'.  but I want it to return not a list of values continuously but rather in the same row position as the filter condition.  the reason is that I eventually want to scatter plot this and I need my x-axis "master" list to be in the same positions.  so what I want to be returned is if C is a numerical value is the following.  Where when the Typist case just is omitted.

```
10

11
3

4


5
```

Comment: You can do it without query

Answer (score 0):

try:

```
=ARRAYFORMULA(IF('Data (QC)'!AF7:AF<>"Typist", 'Data (QC)'!C7:C, ))
```